# Получить ComponentName приложения Android

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте  У меня стоит цель получить ComponentName другого установленного на устройстве приложения. Если точнее, мне нужно получить имя основного класса, которое запускается при нажатии на иконку приложения. Традиционно это *MainActivity*, но зачастую разработчики выбирают другие имена главным Activity.

Comment: эм... в стороннее приложение вы никак не попадёте если я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: `context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.app.package").getComponent()` - как-то так, например.